# How to add pip modules installed from command line into PyDev environment?

Tags: python, macos, pip, pydev, pythonpath

I installed `pip`. Then I installed `PyDev`. Afterwards I installed some packages via `pip`. Now, when I do `import package1` in PyDev, the `package1` cannot be found.

How to integrate packages installed via `pip` into `PyDev`?

I heard about the `PYTHONPATH`, but I cannot figure out where does `pip` install packages (i.e. what is the path to the installed packages?). The OS is `OSX`. I installed pip via `homebrew` (as precise as I can remember it).

## UPDATE 1:

from [[https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#brewed-python-modules]](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/wiki/Homebrew-and-Python#brewed-python-modules%5d) `$(brew --prefix)/lib/pythonX.Y/site-packages` doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2):

To find out where the package is installed:

```
> pip show regex
---
Name: regex
Version: 2014.06.28
Location: /opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requires:
```

Then, go to the `project properties` (i.e. right click on the project => properties => `PyDev PYTHONPATH`) in `PyDev`, add `external lib` source folder. Then refresh (or just rewrite the `import regex` line and save)

Comment: I am new user of MacOS. Just setup Eclipse, PyDev, Python3.7, virtualenvwrapper. Worried why my Eclipse doesnt recognize package installed via `pip`. In Windows/Ubuntu, Eclipse can recognize virtualenvwrapper easily. After reading your solution, now my Eclipse recognize all my packages. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The most practical, long-term solution is to use the method that user @static mentioned for locating `pip` installed packages: `pip show elasticsearch`.
Then use the `location` to choose the corresponding python installation in PyDev.

E.g. (on my Mac) if location comes back as `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` I should use the `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` during Advanced autoconfig in `PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter`.

You can see in the `Libraries` tab that autoconfig pulled in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` automatically, which means that all your `pip` installed packages are available for import.

Comment: @ChristopheRoussy :)

Answer (score 0):

In python, do this:

```
import site
site.getsitepackages()
```

Then copy the given directory. Go to Eclipse --> Windows --> PyDev --> Python Interpreter --> Click on *New Folder* --> Go to the given directory above and add it there.